# Using the text values from one column to lead to output in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a list of cities in one column, Column C.

I have a list of countries which relate to each of those cities. How do I get Excel to look at the Column C, compare to my list of countries (I can store those wherever) and output into Column D with the corresponding country?

Grateful for any advice!

Comment: It sounds like you need a `VLOOKUP`

Answer (score 0):

Enter a *VLOOKUP()* formula in **D1** and copy down.  For example:

[image]